# Failover server for EC2

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, sql-server, rdp, failover

I have one Amazon EC2 instance of Windows Server which is running application with SQL server. Our users from On-premise use RDP to login into this server using Elastic IP and do their work. I want to have failover server (same replica) in the backup so when primary server goes down then it starts failover server automatically. Failover server should also be in different region/zone.

I want to keep backup server turned of to cut off the cost, what are the options to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto-scaling with 'max instances' set to 1. If the only server fails, it'll be terminated and new server created in different or the same AZ, but only in the same region.

If http healthcheck isn't enough then you can create a custom one.

Make sure you have all necessary data on s3 or somewhere else and that you are deploying the data during the new instance start-up, because the failed instance will be terminated with its data/app storage.

You can use Route53 to switch traffic to the new instance in the same or another region.